# DOMXPath/cURL - Trying to get multiple elements into foreach loop

Tags: php, html, dom, curl

I am parsing DOM elements from this page: http://www.sportsdirect.com/kappa-nulent-4-trainers-child-boys-039063?colcode=03906301

Here is the specific DOM that i am focused right now:

```
<ul id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl14_ulSizes" class="sizeButtons" data-clicktoselecttext="Click to select">

    <li id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl14_rptSizes_ctl00_liItem" role="radio" title="Click to select C10 (28)" data-text="C10 (28)" class="tooltip sizeButtonli ">
        <a href="DesktopModules/SportsDirect/ProductDetail/Controls/#" id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl14_rptSizes_ctl00_ancLink">C10 (28)</a>
    </li>

    <li id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl14_rptSizes_ctl01_liItem" role="radio" title="Click to select C11 (29)" data-text="C11 (29)" class="tooltip sizeButtonli ">
        <a href="DesktopModules/SportsDirect/ProductDetail/Controls/#" id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl14_rptSizes_ctl01_ancLink">C11 (29)</a>
    </li>

    <li id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl14_rptSizes_ctl02_liItem" role="radio" title="Click to select C12 (31)" data-text="C12 (31)" class="tooltip sizeButtonli ">
        <a href="DesktopModules/SportsDirect/ProductDetail/Controls/#" id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl14_rptSizes_ctl02_ancLink">C12 (31)</a>
    </li>

    <li id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl14_rptSizes_ctl03_liItem" role="radio" title="Click to select C13 (32)" data-text="C13 (32)" class="tooltip sizeButtonli ">
        <a href="DesktopModules/SportsDirect/ProductDetail/Controls/#" id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl14_rptSizes_ctl03_ancLink">C13 (32)</a>
    </li>

    <li id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl14_rptSizes_ctl04_liItem" role="radio" title="Click to select 1 (33)" data-text="1 (33)" class="tooltip sizeButtonli ">
        <a href="DesktopModules/SportsDirect/ProductDetail/Controls/#" id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl14_rptSizes_ctl04_ancLink">1 (33)</a>
    </li>

    <li id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl14_rptSizes_ctl05_liItem" role="radio" title="Click to select 2 (34)" data-text="2 (34)" class="tooltip sizeButtonli ">
        <a href="DesktopModules/SportsDirect/ProductDetail/Controls/#" id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl14_rptSizes_ctl05_ancLink">2 (34)</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Here is my code:

```
<?PHP 
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "ChosenSite=www; SportsDirect_AnonymousUserCurrency=GBP; language=en-GB");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    $str = curl_exec($curl);  
    curl_close($curl);  

    $html= str_get_html($str);

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($str);

    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);


    $i = 0;
    $Sizes = $xpath->query('//ul[@id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl14_ulSizes"]//li/a');
    foreach ($Sizes->item() as $item) {
        $title = $item->nodeValue;
        $N = $i++;  
?>
        <div class="SizeButtons <?PHP if($N ==  0){ echo "SizeSelected";} ?>" data-title="<?PHP echo $title;?>" data-number="<?PHP echo $N;?>"><?PHP echo $title; ?></div>    
    }         
?>
```

Unfortunatelly it seems that i have mistake in my code somewhere because i can get the results. As you can see there are several DOM elements under `//ul[@id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl14_ulSizes"]//li/a` but i can not get them.

Where is my mistake and how can i fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tested that $doc contains not false?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake!

In the line `foreach ($Sizes->item() as $item) {` just have to remove `->item()` silly me..

Thank to everyone tried to help!